# Why does `assert` macro have value even with `NDEBUG`?

Tags: c++, c

Environment:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
```

---

It is known that function-like macro `assert` for debugging can be disabled with `NDEBUG` defined before the include of `assert.h` (`cassert`). However, reading `/usr/include/assert.h` in my environment, I found the code below.

```
#if defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (2,95)
# define __ASSERT_VOID_CAST static_cast<void>
#else
# define __ASSERT_VOID_CAST (void)
#endif

#ifdef  NDEBUG

# define assert(expr)       (__ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0))

# ifdef __USE_GNU
#  define assert_perror(errnum) (__ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0))
# endif

#else /* Not NDEBUG.  */
```

So, even with `NDEBUG`, `assert` is expanded into some value and thus affect the performance insignificantly but certainly (if no optimization occurs after the preprocess step). Since C++ standard allows function-like macro with empty value, it seems

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(expr)
#endif
```

would be a good implementation.

Is there any reason why non-empty value should be the option?

Comment: The operations static_cast<void>(0) and (void)(0) have no impact on the generated code since they are pure syntactic sugar.

Comment: @user6556709 But makes the compile time slower (a little little little bit)?

Comment: It needs to have the syntax of an expression, so with C you're getting `((void) 0)`.  Your compiler should optimize it away completely, so it should not affect your performance.

Comment: @ynn Any added compile time would be too small to reliably measure.  You might just as well strip all of the whitespace out of your code to speed up compilation for all the difference it will make.  Don't obsess.

Comment: @TomKarzes My old boss believed that less whitespace made compiling faster. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Did he ask you to remove all the comments from your code too?  They're even worse than whitespace ;)

Comment: The only reason I can think of is perhaps setting the CPU's zero-flag, to be consistent with when the assert passed, perhaps?

Comment: @racraman No.  It's optimized away.  No one is checking any zero flags.

Comment: @TomKarzes No, I'm not really worry about the performance or compile time. I would like to know the implementation is just for readability (since empty value is in a sense strange) or has any complex meaning.

Comment: @ynn It's just a minimal void expression that has no side effects.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, that must be true, but that does not explain the redundant-ness of the implementation.

Comment: @ynn I explained it completely.  `((void) 0)` is a *minimal* void-valued expression in C.  An empty string is not, and therefore could result in syntax errors under extreme situations (if the user is doing things like embedding the assert in a comma expression for instance).

Comment: @TomKarzes Sorry, I overlooked the explanation. Now I understand now. Thank you really much.

Comment: Please, imagine the following expression: `asin((assert(x >= -1.0 && x <= 1.0), x));`. Please, note that it uses the `,` operator to insert the evaluation of `assert()` before passing the argument `x`. If `assert()` would be replaced by nothing, then this would break the syntax when `NDEBUG` is defined: `asin((, x))`, but with the "useless" `static_cast<void>(0)`, it will work: `asin((static_cast<void>(0), x))`.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you for a complete example. Hereafter I'll avoid empty macro when not needed particularly.

Comment: Perhaps so an empty function `void foo(void) { assert(1); }` won't be so empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One reason that the macro has a value when `NDEBUG` is defined is because the C standard requires that it has one — it even stipulates what it shall be.

### C11

> **[§7.2 Diagnostics `<assert.h>`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.2)**
>
> ¶1 The header `<assert.h>` defines the `assert` and `static_assert` macros and refers to another macro,
>
> ```
>     NDEBUG
> ```
>
> which is not defined by `<assert.h>`. If `NDEBUG` is defined as a macro name at the point in the source file where `<assert.h>` is included, the `assert` macro is defined simply as
>
> ```
>     #define assert(ignore) ((void)0)
> ```
>
> The `assert` macro is redefined according to the current state of `NDEBUG` each time that `<assert.h>` is included.
>
> ¶2 The `assert` macro shall be implemented as a macro, not as an actual function. If the macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual function, the behavior is undefined.
>
> …
>
> **[7.2.1.1 The `assert` macro](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.2.1.1)**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <assert.h>
>     void assert(scalar expression);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> ¶2 The `assert` macro puts diagnostic tests into programs; it expands to a `void` expression. When it is executed, if `expression` (which shall have a scalar type) is false (that is, compares equal to 0), the `assert` macro writes information about the particular call that failed (including the text of the argument, the name of the source file, the source line number, and the name of the enclosing function -- the latter are respectively the values of the preprocessing macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` and of the identifier `__func__`) on the standard error stream in an implementation-defined format.<sup>191)</sup> It then calls the `abort` function.
>
> **Returns**
>
> ¶3 The `assert` macro returns no value.
>
> <sup>191)</sup> The message written might be of the form:
>
> ```
> Assertion failed: expression, function abc, file xyz, line nnn.
> ```

---

### C++11

The C++11 standard says (§19.3 Assertions) says:

> The header `<cassert>` … provides a macro for documenting C++ program assertions and a mechanism for disabling the assertion checks.
>
> …
>
> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header `<assert.h>`.

So the same rules apply to C++ as to C.  The C++ standard doesn't explicitly call out the differences between the C++ `static_assert` and the C `_Static_assert` (and the definition of `static_assert` as `_Static_assert` in the C version of the `<assert.h>` header).  The net result is much the same, though.